# correct usage of getaddrinfo and getnameinfo

Tags: c, tcp, ip

In my C program, I am using `getaddrinfo` to get IP address from a hostname, and `getnameinfo` to get hostname from IP address. These two functions are complementary. I read in `man getaddrinfo` that I have to use `freeaddrinfo()` function to free up the memory that was allocated for the dynamically allocated linked list `res`. Thus my code looks like this:

```
if ((err = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &res)) != 0) {
  printf("error %d\n", err);
  return 1;
}

addr.s_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in *)(res->ai_addr))->sin_addr.s_addr;
printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(addr));

freeaddrinfo(res);
```

But for `getnameinfo` I don't see any similar function, i.e. `freenameinfo`.

Why do I need to free when using `getaddrinfo` but not for `getnameinfo`. Why do I need to free up at all? Earlier when I used `gethostbyaddr` there was not need to free memory. Why is this different.

And what is the advantage of `getaddrinfo` over `gethostbyaddr`? Is the latter deprecated and should only the former be used? Why ?

Comment: You might like [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html), particularly [section 9.7](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/gethostbynameman.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the man page for `getaddrinfo`, it returns to you a *dynamically allocated linked list*.
Since it performed the memory allocation, it makes sense that it will handle the memory free as well.

> The freeaddrinfo() function frees the memory that was allocated for
>   the dynamically allocated linked list res.

Note also that the function signature includes a `struct addrinfo **`, which is a good hint that the library function is doing the allocation on your behalf and giving you the pointer back.

```
   int getaddrinfo(const char *node, const char *service,
                       const struct addrinfo *hints,
                       struct addrinfo **res);
```

---

For `getnameinfo()`, it requires **the caller** (you) to allocate the `const struct sockaddr *`, so it is **the caller's** (your) responsibility to free it, and there is no corresponding library call to free it.

```
   int getnameinfo(const struct sockaddr *sa, socklen_t salen,
                   char *host, size_t hostlen,
                   char *serv, size_t servlen, int flags);
```

---

From the man page of `gethostbyaddr`, it declares itself to be deprecated.

> The gethostbyname*(), gethostbyaddr*(), herror(), and hstrerror()
>   functions  are  obsolete.   Applications  should  use  getaddrinfo(3),
>   getnameinfo(3),  and gai_strerror(3) instead.

At this point, I usually stop reading, and cease to use `gethostbyaddr`, preferring `getaddrinfo` instead.

*Why are these functions deprecated?* There are probably quite a few reasons, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#gethostbyname.28.29_and_gethostbyaddr.28.29) tells us that the legacy function do not support `IPv6`, and as @R.. mentions below, they are [not](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gethostbyaddr.html) thread safe.

Comment: @R.., Thanks I found a reference and updated the answer.

Comment: Does `getaddrinfo` require freeing memory on error? I don't see that information anywhere. I have a program that uses it, and the only place where free is not called is on error, and valgrind is complaining about lost memory.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist, I'm honestly not sure. If it's not documented anywhere, it's likely a case where one must consult [the source](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c.html).

Comment: @merlin2011 That's reasonable. Thanks for your time.